# bitwise operations on strings with ruby

Tags: ruby, bitwise-operators

How can I perform bitwise operations on strings in ruby?
I would like to do `bitwise &` a 4-byte string with a 4-byte long hex such as `("abcd" & 0xDA2DFFD3)`. I cannot get the byte values of the string. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are always going to operate on 4-byte strings, [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000760) with an argument of `'V'` will treat four bytes as an unsigned long in little-endian byte order.  Using `'N'`  will force network byte order, and using `'L'` will use native order.  Note that `unpack` always returns an array, thus the need to take index 0.

```
>> '0x%X' % ('abcd'.unpack('V')[0] & 0xDA2DFFD3)
=> "0x40216241"
```

If it's not always four bytes, you can call `String#bytes` to get the bytes of the string, and then you can use `Enumerable#inject` to accumulate the bytes into a number.

```
>> "abcd".bytes.inject {|x, y| (x << 8) | y}
=> 1633837924
>> "abcd".bytes.inject {|x, y| (x << 8) | y}.to_s(16)
=> "61626364"
>> "abcd".bytes.inject {|x, y| (x << 8) | y} & 0xDA2DFFD3
=> 1075864384
>> "0x%X" % ("abcd".bytes.inject {|x, y| (x << 8) | y} & 0xDA2DFFD3)
=> "0x40206340"
```

This is "safe" as long as you're using ASCII strings.  If you start using multi-byte strings, you're going to get "odd" results.